# Back button fails to get page from history in FF browser with Document Expired message

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am asp.net webform app and i am listing all blogs using paging. I am using Update panel for listing so that user don't have to leave the page.

In order to add back functionality i have to remove the UpdatePanel and add following code to add back functionality

```
var URL = document.URL;
var URLNew = "";
var pageNo = "";
$(".paging >  a").click(function(){
    page = $(this).text();
    newURL = URL + '?'+pageNo ;
    //window.history.replaceState(null, URLNew , URLNew );
    history.pushState(stateObj, URLNew , URLNew );
```

});

This code works fine in Chrome and IE but fails in FF v47. I deleted history also but this doesn't work properly in FF.

Let us say i navigate to  page 1 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 some time back history works for 1 or last 2 page but if i want to navigate to first page it breaks and return error "Document Expired"

Comment: Do you send a "Cache-control: no-cache" header? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching_FAQ

Comment: @le_m, Just cross checked to make sure. I am not using such meta tag in my code.

Comment: Not in your HTML, but in your HTTP-headers (press [F12] for developer console, goto network tab).

Comment: @le_m, I cant see any `Cache-Control` in HTTP-header section also

Comment: I tried same in FF Private mode it worked better than normal mode but broke once otherwise it worked all the way down to last page in history. Not sure why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing bit on research and going through several search links cam across a link which mentioned "Document Expired message" in FF is due to cache disk space limit. I crease the Cache from 10MB to 100MB and issue seems to be resolved for now.